# Array of pointers to functions C++

Tags: c++, arrays, function, pointers

I have 3 functions with the same signature. I need to initialize an array with pointers to functions. 
I have:

```
typedef void(*sorting_func) (int* a, int n);
```

and functions:

```
class Sortings {
public:
    static void bubble_sort(int a[], int n);
    static void bubble_aiverson_1(int a[], int n);
    static void bubble_aiverson_2(int a[], int n);
};
```

I need an array with pointer in this class to use like this:

```
Sortings::array[0]...
```

Functions can be not static.

Comment: Looks like you're almost done. What specifif issue do you have?

Comment: Without static functions, the type of your sorting function is `void(Sortings::*)(int *, int);`. Depending on your needs, `std::function` could be an option, too.

Comment: If you need them to be non static member functions they will not have the signature you appear to desire. However you may not need that signature. You can have your sortings object have a static array of pointers to member. So you could do some_instance_of_Sortings.*Sortings::array[i](some_int_ptr,size); better yet you could define operator[] to do the above with much more syntactic sugar.

Comment: It looks like Sortings does not model anything - that is, you never create a Sortings object (instance). If that is the case, it shouldn't be a class. If you just want to wrap a few functions together so that they don't "pollute" the global namespace, rather have your three functions as normal non-member functions in a Sortings namespace. A benefit of this is that then they will match sorting-func's definition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a `vector` of `std::function`, i.e.

```
std::vector<std::function(void(int*,int)>> sortingFunctions;
```

Then, depending on the case you can directly push back free functions, or use a lambda to push back a member function the following way:

```
//Capturing `this` in the lambda implies the vector is a member of the class
//Otherwise, you must capture an instance of the class you want to call the 
//function on.
std::function<void(int*,int)> myMemberFunction = [this](int* a, int n){
    this->memberFunction(a,n);
}
```

sortingFunctions.push_back(myMemberFunction);

assuming you create the vector in a member function of your `Sorting` class.

[**See a live example here**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3bde03028becef23)

Comment: I have an error in Xcode:
`Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "Sortings::bubble_sort(int*, int)", referenced from:
      Sortings::Sortings()::'lambda'(int*, int)::operator()(int*, int) const in main.o
  "Sortings::bubble_aiverson_1(int*, int)", referenced from:
      Sortings::Sortings()::'lambda'(int*, int)::operator()(int*, int) const in main.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)`

Comment: You likely forgot to implement your functions... Please try to solve your generic programmation problems and come back with issues related to this specific topic (the array of functions).